# Adding (concatenating) tuples to lists in Python

Tags: python, list, concatenation, tuples, augmented-assignment

In Python3, let me define simple a list and tuple as follows:

```
In [1]: alist = [1, 2, 3]
In [2]: atuple = (4, 5, 6)
```

If I attempt an "add" (+) of the tuple to the list and assign that to the original list I get a TyperError:

```
In [3]: alist = alist + atuple
TypeError: can only concatenate list (not "tuple") to list`
```

However, if I use the augmented assignment operator, it will append atuple to alist, it will work as intended:

```
In [4]: alist += atuple
In [5]: alist
Out[5]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

So, logically, why does the augmented assignment operator work, In [4], while the long form, In [3], throws are Error?

I want to understand why the augmented assignment operation allows appending a tuple to a list while the + operator does not.

Comment: _So, logically, why does the augmented assignment operator work_ Because under the hood, they actually have different behavior.  See the dupe question link.

Comment: Yes, I see that works. To me logically alist = alist + atuple should work as well. Apparently the __add__ magic method for the list class doesn't allow other iterable types to be added (concatenated).